# Passing Multiple Parameters in Slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to send two parameters in a Slot but i get the following error.

'layoutProperty' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified

'layoutProperty' is a QVBoxLayout.

```
void Container::CreatePositionAnimationUI(QHBoxLayout *layout1 , 
  QHBoxLayout *layout2 , QHBoxLayout *layout3 , QVBoxLayout 
 *layoutProperty )
   {
     QPushButton *pushButtonKey1 = new QPushButton;
     QPushButton *pushButtonKey2 = new QPushButton;
     QPushButton *pushButtonKey3 = new QPushButton;
     layout1->addWidget(pushButtonKey1);
     layout2->addWidget(pushButtonKey2);
     layout3->addWidget(pushButtonKey3);    

      QObject::connect(pushButtonKey1, &QPushButton::clicked , this, 
      [this] {SetPositionKeyGUIParameters(1 ,layoutProperty); });  // Get error on this line

   }
```

Comment: change to `[this, layoutProperty]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
QObject::connect(pushButtonKey1, &QPushButton::clicked , this, [&] 
{SetPositionKeyGUIParameters(1 , layoutProperty); });
```